# Angular: How to overlap input in a card game, depending on who play the card first?

Tags: html, css, angular, typescript, layer

We are currently implementing a card game.

Following the corresponding html code to the image:

```
<!-- Middle area for played cards. -->
<div *ngIf="this.index < 25" fxLayout="row" fxLayoutAlign="center center" fxLayoutGap="-5%" style="width: 50%">
  <div>
    <input class="buttonCards" type="image" src={{playedCardsWithImage[1].imgSrc}} width="50%" height="88%"
           disabled/>
  </div>
  <div fxLayout="column" fxLayoutGap="-100%">
    <input class="buttonCards" type="image" src={{playedCardsWithImage[2].imgSrc}} width="50%" height="88%"
           disabled/>
    <input class="buttonCards" type="image" src={{playedCardsWithImage[0].imgSrc}} width="50%" height="88%"
           disabled/>
  </div>
  <div fxLayout="row" fxLayoutAlign="center end">
    <input class="buttonCards" type="image" src={{playedCardsWithImage[3].imgSrc}} width="50%" height="88%"
           disabled/>
  </div>
</div>
```

[image]

Depending, on which player plays his card first, the priority of the layers should be changed. 
That means: If the bottom player plays his card first, his card should be displayed on the bottom layer, while the left players card should be displayed one layer above and so on.

What is a good and clean way to implement that?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `CSS` `z-index` property by incrementing this value as the players play their cards.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/z-index